# Trouble using WCS on 3DEP

Tags: gdal, wcs

This page https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/services/ includes a link under "WCS Services" that lists a number of subdatasets.  This command

```
gdalnfo "https://elevation.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WCS"
```

works fine.  I have been retrieving elevation data from the first subdataset:

SUBDATASET_1_NAME=WCS:https://elevation.nationalmap.gov:443/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?version=2.0.1&coverage=DEP3Elevation
SUBDATASET_1_DESC=DEP3Elevation

and most of the time it works but I think I must be doing something wrong since sometimes there are large missing areas.

For instance this area (Boston) works just fine:

```
gdal_translate "WCS:https://elevation.nationalmap.gov:443/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?version=2.0.1&coverage=DEP3Elevation" test.tif -projwin -71.07 42.36 -71.03 42.33 -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 100 100
```

but this command with only a different "projwin" (in Colorado) is about 75% missing:

```
gdal_translate "WCS:https://elevation.nationalmap.gov:443/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?version=2.0.1&coverage=DEP3Elevation" test.tif -projwin -107.03 37.28 -107 37.25 -projwin_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 100 100
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong here and how to fix it?

I am using a very recent OSGeo4W featuring GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a look in QGIS and it looks fine to me:

[image]

Zooming in on your 2nd bounding box also looks fine (though you seem to have specified a TL, BR box rather than the more normal BL, TR. However I think GDAL should handle that fine).

[image]

Comment: Switching to BL,TR causes gdal_translate to return an error `ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 8.12298e+06 1.4335e+07 3340 -4196 has negative width and/or height.`  unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Those are just random numbers, I meant bottom left, top right so the numbers should be identical but reordered

Comment: Projwin in gdal_translate is, as documented, `-projwin <ulx> <uly> <lrx> <lry>`. GDAL utilities have some pecularities.

Comment: The request that GDAL sends (capture it by adding `--debug on`) is `https://elevation.nationalmap.gov:443/arcgis/services/3DEPElevation/ImageServer/WCSServer?SERVICE=WCS&REQUEST=GetCoverage&VERSION=2.0.1&COVERAGEID=DEP3Elevation&SUBSET=x%28-20037507.0672000013,-11911185.14836644%29&SUBSET=y%284474012.1150791775,4478208.115037268%29&SCALESIZE=x%2833%29,y%2842%29&Format=image/tiff`. Unfortunately response is multipart and I do not know how to extract the tiff part. I would have played with SCALESIZE values, it may be that the server has problems with resampling.

Comment: @IanTurton - They were not random numbers.  Although (as user30184 said) I know that gdal_translate wants UL,LR, I figured you were suggesting switching to BL,TR as a test.  But I guess you were just pointing out that BL, TR is more typical.  If I'm missing something, please clarify.  Thanks!